# How to configure pfSense WAN and LAN to use as a proxy server?

Tags: networking, proxy, pfsense

We have a network configured like this:

Internet -> ASA -> L3 switch:VLAN1 - Servers (IP/23); VLAN2 - PCs (IP/22);

There is a communication between servers and PCs and thay are in a different IP range.

Now we need to put pfSense as a proxy on servers side, and then direct web browsers on PCs to go through it.

Our question is:
How can we configure WAN and LAN on pfSense and which address we need to use as a proxy in internet settings on browsers, without changing IPs on every PC?

What is the best course of action in our case?

Thanks!